# Parsing integers in serverless.yml to use MemoryDB's ClusterEndpoint.Port in Environment Variable

Tags: aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I'm creating a MemoryDB cluster for my serverless function, but the [Port for the MemoryDB endpoint is an Integer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-memorydb-cluster-endpoint.html#cfn-memorydb-cluster-endpoint-port), so when I try to set an environment variable to pass the endpoint URL to my function I get an error

```
Error:
Cannot resolve serverless.yml: Variables resolution errored with:
  - Cannot resolve variable at "provider.environment.MEMORYDB_ENDPOINT": String value consist of variable which resolve with non-string value
```

Example serverless.yml file:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  # [...]
  environment:
    MEMORYDB_PORT: ${self:custom.MEMORYDB_PORT}
# [...]
custom:
  MEMORYDB_PORT: !GetAtt MemoryDB.ClusterEndpoint.Port
```

I've tried with Fn::Join, Fn::Sub (plugin) and others but they all expect strings as arguments.

I'm not planning on using a custom port so I can always assume the default, however I feel like I'm missing some thing here.

Is there a way to parse integers in serverless/cloudformation somehow? Or at least convert that port into a string?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know serverless doesn't allow having functions in .yaml file, since that is just a declaration.

You could have a custom plugin: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/plugins/custom-variables

It would looks something similar

```
    export class MaxBatchingWindowIntParser {
      public configurationVariablesSources: object;

      public constructor() {
        this.configurationVariablesSources = {
          parseValue: {
           resolve({ address }) {
             return {
               value: Number.parseInt(address, 10),
             };
            },
           },
          };
         }
        }
```